# HTML // CSS // JavaScript : button or input doesn't show up on web

Tags: javascript, css, html

My form uses some logic conditionals based on the user's text input. I wrote a JavaScript function for the conditional and decided to execute this function when the user hits a button, after typing in the text-field. When I run my code on a live preview from Brackets.io, the buttons are visible. But when I open the .html file on the web, the buttons don't show up.

I tried using `<input>` with type="submit" to make it a button but this doesn't show up too.

HTML:

```
<button id="funcCond">Proceed</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -300%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -300%);
  display: block;
  width: 70vw;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.8, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the JavaScript code?

Comment: You have `opacity: 0;`. Do you have another piece of code that modifies that value?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<button type="submit" id="funcCond">proceed</button>`

or:

`<input type="button" value="proceed"/>`

..and make sure to modify your opacity value to `1`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding (type) attribute to your html button`<button type="button" id="funcCond">proceed</button>` or instead you can use the input element with type button `<input type="button">`

Comment: Why would that affect whether the button is visible? It only changes what happens when you click on the button.